# Ada - Sending HTTP response with GNAT.Sockets

Tags: sockets, http, http-headers, ada, gnat

I got a problem with sending headers though socket in ADA. 
Here is the code:

```ada
    Address.Addr := Addresses(Get_Host_By_Name(Host_Name), 1);
    Address.Port := 80;
    Create_Socket(Server);
    Set_Socket_Option(Server, Socket_Level, (Reuse_Address, True));
    Bind_Socket(Server, Address);
    Listen_Socket(Server);
    Accept_Socket(Server, Socket, Address);
    Channel := Stream(Socket);

    Receive_Socket(Socket, Data, Offset);
    for I in 1 .. Offset loop
        Append(Request, Character'Val(Data(I)));
    end loop;

    String'Output(Channel, 
         "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" & CRLF & 
         "Date: Fri, 09 Jan 2015 01:08:54 GMT" & CRLF & CRLF & 
         "something"
      );
```

I am using as a client Firefox Browser. When i am reading the GET-request via socket it's all great. The problem comes up when i am trying to send the response. After the last line in quoted code, my browser gets only `HTTP/0.9 200 OK` (Checked via Live HTTP headers) and no content at all is being displayed (Which is a little weird for me because i just send `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`).

Would really appreciate a little help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String’Output` “writes the value of Item to Stream, including any bounds or discriminants” ([ARM 13.13.2 (21)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-13-2.html#p21)).

`String` is an indefinite type, so the string you’re trying to output does indeed have bounds, and what you are sending is the index of the first character of the string as a 4-byte binary number, the index of the last character of the string as a 4-byte binary number, and then the string.

Use `String’Write` instead (see ARM 13.13.2 (9)).

Comment: Finally I get what was wrong with my code. The solution was very simple. I am embarrassed I came up with that after such a long time. But it was a good lesson. Your advice was correct(I needed to use `Write` instead of `Output`). Another thing was that i needed to close the socket I was writing into. Thanks for all the support I receive :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Ada but your code looks wrong anyway.

- You read the header from `Socket` and simply assume that the complete header is within a single read. Instead you should read lines from the socket until you get the end of the header (single line with only CRLF).
- <strike>You write to `Channel`, whatever this is. Instead you need to write to the same `Socket` you've got the request from.</strike>

> my browser gets only HTTP/0.9 200 OK

You are probably only seeing a pseudo-header added by the browser because there was nothing useful. In reality HTTP 0.9 [has no response header at all](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) (i.e. there is not "HTTP/0.9"), so this is probably made up by the browser because it got something without any valid HTTP header. To see what really is going on do a packet capture. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27885183/3081018) of Simon Wright to see where this bogus data come from.

Comment: Steffen, `Channel` is a `Stream` whose target is indeed the original `Socket`. So that’s not the problem here.

Comment: My bad, I did not look close enough. But together with your answer this explains the HTTP/0.9 - that is the browser just interprets bogus data as HTTP/0.9 because they lack a proper HTTP header.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I know about that my reading from this socket is not best for now. It was just a temporary solution. Changing that `String'Output` to `String'Write` made my browser not geting anything at all. I'll try to check it with packet capture later today.